# Dynamically consuming the REST service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, wcf-rest, wadl

We are looking for a solution to consume a REST full service dynamically in C#. It is something like Wcf test client. In our application, user should be able to provide a service url and then select the required data to be used in the application.

Normally, we will get the WSDL in case of SOAP based service, that describes all about the service, like available methods, parameters to be passed, response type, etc. We, then can use the response, probably using reflection if we execute it dynamically.

How can we achieve the similar information if the services are RESTfull? How do we know what type of data it returns? What is the schema? etc.

I found something called WADL and RSDL can be used to know about the RESTfull services. Do all the REST full services always provide that? If so then how? If not then how will I get to know about the services?

Please note that in our application, we want our user to register any RESTfull service at runtime and consume the response in the application, so we don't want to code for each type of services.

WCF support dynamic discovery in case SOAP. Does it support something similar for REST?

Comment: This is similar to the [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111646/restful-services-wsdl-equivalent) question. You can refer the article [Here](http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/documenting-rest-services-wsdl-and-wadl.html) as well.

Comment: Take a look on [Nelibur](https://github.com/Nelibur/Nelibur), you'll able to send any data with fixed ServiceContract (Get, Post, Put, Delete)